# Appendix and beamerbutton

Tags: beamer, slideshow, button

I'm making a presentation using the beamer, and some slides contains some details which can be shown using a click-on button to a slide which will be in the appendix. I want this slide to be shown only when I click on that button.

Is it possible to hide the appendix from the presentation slides but keeping the ability to click on that button and show the wanted slide.

As an example:  (I want the slide named by "More Details" to be hidden from the presentation pdf file)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[label=slide1]
   text1

   show more details   \hyperlink{more-details}{\beamerbutton{show more details}}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
   text2
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
   text3
\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\appendix     

\begin{frame}[label=more-details,noframenumbering]{More Details}

Details

\hyperlink{slide1}{\beamerbutton{Back}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: While you wait for an answer to this question, can you go back to your previous ones and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, although, this doesn't solve my problem!

Comment: There are not many alternatives. If you want a slide accessible by clicking, it either has to be in the pdf you are showing or in another file. It cannot appear out of nowhere. Why is an appendix at the end of the presentation such a problem?